# Calculating expected value for a betting event given: Decimal Odds, Stake, Potential Profit, & Implied Probability?

Tags: probability, gambling

I am trying to get the expected value of a bet on a UFC money line fight (betting which fighter will win)

decimal odds at: $1.6$

Stake: $$30$

Potential Profit ($PP$): $(1.6 * 30) - 30$

Implied Probability of Win ($Pw$): $(1/1.6)$

Implied Probability of Loss ($Pl$): $1 - (1/1.6)$

Given the formula of E(x) is: $(Pw*PP) - (Pl * Stake)$

I keep on getting zero, so I am doing deff. doing the probability of a loss incorrectly.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. *How* did you get $0$?

Comment: Not following.  If you assume that the bet is priced to exactly match the true probability of winning, then of course the expectation is $0$.  Usually, in betting on sports events, the gambler assumes that they have a better sense of the true probability than the market does.

Comment: So is my formula for expected value incorrect? Some sports betting websites show the expected value as $0.05 [https://www.actionnetwork.com/betting-calculators/odds-value-calculator] this website for example shows given a $30 wager, and -166 American odds (1.6 decimal odds) at implied probability of 62.5% the expected value is $0.05. How did they get to this calculation?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. I got 0 because [(1/1.6)*18] - [1 - (1/1.6) * 30 ] =  11.25 - 11.25. This is not correct

Comment: I did figure it out, I would need the odds for the opposing fighter as well. If the F1 has odds of 1.6, the odds are 1/1.6, the second fighter is at 2.6 so odds are 1/2.6. Then I use those values in the new one E(x) = (Pw * Profit) +  (Pl * (-Stake))